# Solr DataImportHandler doesn't work with XML Files

Tags: xml, solr, indexing, dataimporthandler

I'm very new to Solr. I succeeded in indexing data from my sql database via DIH. Now I want to import xml files and index them also via DIH but it just won't work!
My data-config.xml looks like this:

```
<dataConfig>
    <dataSource type="FileDataSource" encoding="UTF-8" />
    <document>
    <entity name="dir" 
            processor="FileListEntityProcessor" 
            baseDir="/bla/test2" 
            fileName=".*xml"
            stream="true"
            recursive="false"       
            rootEntity="false">
            <entity name="PubmedArticle"
                    processor="XPathEntityProcessor"
                    transformer="RegexTransformer"
                    stream="true"
                    forEach="/PubmedArticle"
                    url="${dir.fileAbsolutePath}">


                <field column="journal" xpath="//Name[.='journal']/following-sibling::Value/text()" />
                <field column="authors" xpath="//Name[.='authors']/following-sibling::Value/text()" />

             ..etc
```

And i have the following fields in schema.xml:

`<field name="journal" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
<field name="authors" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />`

When i run Solr i get no errors and no document is indexed:

```
<str name="Total **Rows Fetched**">**2000**</str>
<str name="Total **Documents Skipped**">**0**</str>
<str name="Full Dump Started">2012-02-01 14:59:17</str>
<str name="">Indexing completed. **Added/Updated: 0 documents.** Deleted 0 documents.
```

Can anyone tell me what i did wrong?! I have even double checked the path syntax...

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest reviewing the answers to a similar question:

[Need help indexing XML files into Solr using DataImportHandler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8858856/need-help-indexing-xml-files-into-solr-using-dataimporthandler/8862142#8862142)

Using a scripting language like groovy is a lot less complicated and easier to test.

Comment: Well i'm not familiar with groovy, although, the example looks easy, but i still don't even know what to do with that script! However, i did find out that it indeed has something to do with the xpath expression. The Xml files look like this: <Feature>
  <Name className="java.lang.String">journal</Name>
  <Value className="java.lang.String">The Journal of organic chemistry</Value>
</Feature>.Although the expression is correct, when i change it to only '//Name' DIH indexes document, but thats not what i want. //Name[text()='journal'] won't work as well :( I just can't understand why!

Answer (score 0):

I recently encountered the same problem when trying the same thing; i.e., when using *FileListEntityProcessor* (to read multiple local .xml files) and *XPathEntityProcessor* (to grab certain XML elements).

**Root Cause**: is in this line:

```
<field column="journal" xpath="//Name[.='journal']/following-sibling::Value/text()" />
```

**Explanation**: the argument for the xpath attribute ("//Name..."), while valid xpath syntax, is NOT supported by Solr. The "Apache Solr 4.4 Reference Guide" simply says:
*The XPath expression which will extract the content from the record for this field. Only a subset of Xpath syntax is supported.*

**Solution**: Change the argument for xpath to be the full path from the document root:

```
<field column="journal" xpath="/full/path/from/root/of/document/Name[.='journal']/following-sibling::Value/text()" />
```