# Is it possible to call dih with a path to a file?

Tags: solr, indexing, dih

I'm working on a project where a log is generated after each operation. Is it possible to call DIH whenever a new log is generated with a path to this file as a parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally I havent tried doing it but there are planty of examples (and also questions) around like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8858856/need-help-indexing-xml-files-into-solr-using-dataimporthandler/8862142#8862142) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9097223/solr-dataimporthandler-doesnt-work-with-xml-files) and [a blog post](http://solr.pl/en/2011/08/16/data-import-handler-%E2%80%93-import-from-solr-xml-files/)... I dont know the format of your logs but if it is possible for XML as you can see from the links, it could be applied for your case too...

the other workaround could be using a cronjob or another thing to post your logs in a time period like every 5 or 10 minutes... or directly detecting the log creation and then posting it to the solr server.