# Indexing XML files in Solr with DataImportHandler

Tags: xml, solr, dih

I have to index some XML files. The structure of the files is http://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/efetch.fcgi?db=pubmed&id=24069587,1568,4069587,2598965,18000000,254875,587895&rettype=fasta&retmode=xml

I've edited the Solr config files:

**data-config.xml**

```
<dataConfig>
    <dataSource type="FileDataSource" encoding="UTF-8" />
    <document>
    <entity name="PubmedArticle"
        processor="XPathEntityProcessor"
        stream="true"
        pk="pmc"
        forEach="/pmc-articleset/article"
        url="C:\Users\hp\Desktop\idpSOlr - Copy\apache-solr-4.0.0\example\solr\collection1\conf\pmcsampleDownloaded.xml" 
        transformer="RegexTransformer,DateFormatTransformer"
        >
        <field column="journal-title" xpath="/pmc-articleset/article/front/journal-meta/journal-title-group/journal-title"/>
        <filed column="pmc"  xpath="/pmc-articleset/article/front/article-meta/article-id[@pub-id-type='pmc']"/>
        <filed column="pmid"  xpath="/pmc-articleset/article/front/article-meta/article-id[@pub-id-type='pmid']"/>
        <filed column="other"  xpath="/pmc-articleset/article/front/article-meta/article-id[@pub-id-type='other']"/>
        <filed column="doi"  xpath="/pmc-articleset/article/front/article-meta//article-id[@pub-id-type='doi']"/>
        <field column="text" xpath="/pmc-articleset/article/front/article-meta/tittle-group/article-title" />



    </entity>
</document>
```

and
**schema.xml**

```
<schema name="pubmed" version="1.1">
<types>
    <fieldType name="nametext" class="solr.TextField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true"/>         
    <fieldType name="integer" class="solr.IntField" omitNorms="true"/>
    <fieldType name="long" class="solr.LongField" omitNorms="true"/>
    <fieldType name="float" class="solr.FloatField" omitNorms="true"/>
    <fieldType name="double" class="solr.DoubleField" omitNorms="true"/>
    <fieldType name="sint" class="solr.SortableIntField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true"/>
    <fieldType name="slong" class="solr.SortableLongField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true"/>
    <fieldType name="sfloat" class="solr.SortableFloatField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true"/>
    <fieldType name="sdouble" class="solr.SortableDoubleField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true"/>
    <fieldType name="date" class="solr.DateField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true"/>
    <fieldType name="random" class="solr.RandomSortField" indexed="true" /> 
     <!-- A text field that only splits on whitespace for exact matching of words -->
    <fieldType name="text_ws" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer>
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
    <fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
        <analyzer type="index">
            <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt"/>
            <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
            <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
        </analyzer>
        <analyzer type="query">
            <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
            <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt"/>
            <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
            <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
        </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
    <fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
        <analyzer type="index">
            <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        </analyzer>
        <analyzer type="query">
            <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
            <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
    <fieldType name="alphaOnlySort" class="solr.TextField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true">
    <analyzer>   
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.TrimFilterFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory"
            pattern="([^a-z])" replacement="" replace="all"
        />
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
    <fieldtype name="ignored" stored="false" indexed="false" class="solr.StrField" /> 
    <fieldType name="string" class="solr.StrField" sortMissingLast="true" />    
</types>
<fields>
    <field name="journal-title" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" /> 
    <field name="pmc" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="false" multiValued="false" /> 
    <field name="pmid" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="false" multiValued="false" />
    <field name="other"  type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="false" multiValued="false" />     
    <field name="doi" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="false" multiValued="false" />        
    <field name="article-title" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" required="false" multiValued="true" /> 
    <!--<field name="surname" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="true" /> 
    <field name="given-name" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="true" />       
    <field name="pub-date_day" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="true" />-->
    <field name="text" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="true"/>
    <field name="_version_" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
</fields>
<uniqueKey>pmc</uniqueKey>
<solrQueryParser defaultOperator="OR"/>
</schema>
```

And I have configured a request handler as:

```
<requestHandler name="/dataimport" class="org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler">
<lst name="defaults">
<str name="config">data-config.xml</str>
</lst>
```

When I issue a full-import request to Solr 
(`http://localhost:8983/solr/dataimport?command=full-import`) 
for the first time, I get this response:

```
<response>
    <lst name="responseHeader">
        <int name="status">0</int>
        <int name="QTime">18</int>
    </lst>
    <lst name="initArgs">
        <lst name="defaults">
    <str name="config">data-config.xml</str>
    </lst>
    </lst>
    <str name="command">full-import</str>
    <str name="status">idle</str>
    <str name="importResponse"/>
    <lst name="statusMessages"/>
    <str name="WARNING">
    This response format is experimental. It is likely to change in the future.
    </str>
    </response>
```

And for the second time, I get this response:

```
<response>
    <lst name="responseHeader">
        <int name="status">0</int>
        <int name="QTime">6</int>
    </lst>
    <lst name="initArgs">
    <lst name="defaults">
        <str name="config">data-config.xml</str>
    </lst>
    </lst>
    <str name="command">full-import</str>
    <str name="status">idle</str>
    <str name="importResponse"/>
    <lst name="statusMessages">
        <str name="Total Requests made to DataSource">0</str>
        <str name="Total Rows Fetched">0</str>
        <str name="Total Documents Skipped">0</str>
        <str name="Full Dump Started">2013-10-12 20:45:12</str>
        <str name="">
        Indexing completed. Added/Updated: 0 documents. Deleted 0 documents.
        </str>
        <str name="Committed">2013-10-12 20:45:12</str>
        <str name="Total Documents Processed">0</str>
        <str name="Time taken">0:0:0.270</str>
    </lst>
    <str name="WARNING">
        This response format is experimental. It is likely to change in the future.
    </str>
</response>
```

When I query Solr, I find that no documents are indexed. Could anyone help me out with this? Are the schema and data config right?

Comment: Have you checked the Solr logs? You can get the logs from the Solr Admin interface (in the Logging section). You could find the logs and post the stacktrace here so that it'll be easier to understand the problem.

Comment: And try issuing this: http://localhost:8983/solr/dataimport?command=full-import&commit=true&optimize=true

Comment: I find it easier to parse XML, using groovy, and then load the index using solrj: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8858856/need-help-indexing-xml-files-into-solr-using-dataimporthandler/8862142#8862142

Comment: 13:04:12 WARNING SolrCore New index directory detected: old=null new=solr/collection1\data\index/  this is what is in the logging section

Comment: when i use posting java -jar post. jar pmcsampleDownloaded.xml  in the cmd window shows "posting files...,  1 files indexed"
 and in logging section
  13:14:12 WARNING XMLLoader XML parser reported schema validation in "http://dtd.nlm.nih.gov/ncbi/pmc/articleset/nlm-articleset-2.0.dtd",​ line 226,​ column 30: Attribute xml:space has to be defined of type enumerated,​ and have 1 or 2 values,​ 'default' and/or 'preserve'
 is reeated a lot of times