# Apache Solr Data Import Handler is not indexing xml files

Tags: xml, apache, solr, lucene

I am new to solr. I have gone through the solr wiki tutorial and I am trying to index some xml files in solr using DataImportHandler, but it seems not indexing my data.

My data-config.xml is:

```
<dataConfig>
  <dataSource type="FileDataSource"/><document>
  <entity name="f" processor="FileListEntityProcessor" fileName=".*xml" newerThan="'NOW-3DAYS'" 
   recursive="true" rootEntity="false" dataSource="null" baseDir="C:/Users/admin/Desktop/Project_work/ImageCLEF(Dataset)/all_text/all_text/metadata/sample">

   <entity name="image" processor="XPathEntityProcessor" forEach="/image/text[@xml:lang='en']" url="${f.fileAbsolutePath}" >
     <field column="name"        xpath="/image/name"/>
     <field column="description" xpath="/image/text/description"/>
     <field column="caption"     xpath="/image/text/caption"/>
     <field column="comment"     xpath="/image/text/comment"/>
   </entity>
  </entity>
</document>
</dataConfig>
```

Here is how my sample xml file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<image id="140017" file="images/15/140017.jpg">
 <name>MTwainAppletonsJournal4July74.jpg</name>
 <text xml:lang='en'>
    <description>adsadasd</description>
    <comment>sddasd</comment>
    <caption article="text/en/2/310906">1874 engraving of Twain</caption>
 </text>
 <text xml:lang="de">
    <description/>
    <comment />
    <caption />
 </text>
 <text xml:lang="fr">
    <description />
    <comment />
    <caption />
 </text>
 <comment>({{Information |Description= |Source= |Date= |Author= |Permission= |other_versions= }})</comment>
 <license>Public Domain</license>
 </image>
```

In my schema.xml:

```
<fields>
  <field name="_version_" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <field name="name" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
  <field name="description" type="text_en_splitting" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"/>
  <field name="caption" type="text_en_splitting" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"/>
  <field name="comment" type="text_en_splitting" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"/>

  <field name="text" type="text_en_splitting" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true"/>
 </fields>
 <uniqueKey>name</uniqueKey>
```

I have configured data import handler in solr-config.xml as:

```
 <requestHandler name="/dataimport" class="org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler">
 <lst name="defaults">
 <str name="config">C:/solr-4.6.1/example/solr/collection1/conf/data-config.xml</str>
 </lst>
 </requestHandler>
```

After using Solr Import URL:

```
 http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/dataimport?command=full-import
```

I am getting the following response:

```
<response>
 <lst name="responseHeader">
 <int name="status">0</int>
 <int name="QTime">4</int>
 </lst>
 <lst name="initArgs">
 <lst name="defaults">
 <str name="config">C:/solr-4.6.1/example/solr/collection1/conf/data-config.xml</str>
 </lst>
 </lst>
 <str name="command">full-import</str>
 <str name="status">idle</str>
 <str name="importResponse"/>
 <lst name="statusMessages">
 <str name="Total Requests made to DataSource">0</str>
 <str name="Total Rows Fetched">2</str>
 <str name="Total Documents Skipped">0</str>
 <str name="Full Dump Started">2014-02-16 16:48:36</str>
 <str name="">
      <b>Indexing completed. Added/Updated: 0 documents. Deleted 0 documents.</b>
 </str>
 <str name="Committed">2014-02-16 16:48:36</str>
 <str name="Total Documents Processed">0</str>
 <str name="Time taken">0:0:0.23</str>
 </lst>
 <str name="WARNING">
      <b>This response format is experimental. It is likely to change in the future.</b>
 </str>
 </response>
```

I am tired of searching for the solution in the internet/Stackoverflow, but nothing solved my problem. Please help me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: For an alternative approach: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8858856/need-help-indexing-xml-files-into-solr-using-dataimporthandler/8862142#8862142

Comment: @MarkO'Connor : Didn't know what was the problem with DIH but the suggested alternative approach solved my problem. Thanks.